# How to create table and search for that table in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a question a long question.

Can someone help me or tell me how can i create a table in angular with data that i need to get it from API. I am actually creating library management project and the main feature is to reserve books from the library. Page I am implementing right know is the search page, user should be allowed to search the books and the data should be represented to him in a table with a search bar on top and search button next to search bar. Books need to searched by author after typing three letters and books in the table should be filtered and showed as user is typing. I know i need service which i already created. I know i need two separate components one for search(so i can use it to search users afterwards) and one for the table(grid) or whatever. Now my question is what do i need to have in a components? How can i take the data and display it in a table? and How can i search through and how can i apply filters.

This is what i created so far:

search-books.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { environment } from '../environment';
import { Book } from '../model/book';


@Injectable()

export class SearchBooksService {

    public url = environment.serverUrl + '/api/books';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getBooks(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
}
```

search-books.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { SearchBooksService } from '../service/search-books.service';
import { Book } from '../model/book';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/search-books/search-books.component.html'
})

export class SearchBooksComponent implements OnInit {

    books: Book[] = [];
    loading = false;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private service: SearchBooksService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getBooks().subscribe(
            data => {
                this.books = data.json();
            },
            error => {
                console.error(error);
            },
            () =>
        {
            //on success
            console.log(this.books);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

and i have search-books.component.html as an empty html so far.

When tested component is working fine i have all the data needed in the `console.log(this.books)` this is working fine. How to proceed and how to create those components and that search and table. Please help, and thank you in advance to everyone !

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this in angular is to use datatable extension , the data will be privided from the backend by http calls. also the search , sort options will be already existing , all u have to do is to install and provide data for that table
here a link for the data table example : https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard-pro-angular2/#/tables/datatables.net

I hope really that i helped u , otherwise i will be here in case u need more support.

Comment: thank you really much i saw this already but it's not working on my project. Maybe another idea ?

Comment: it is supposed to work , but u need to install angular material, pls try this : https://www.positronx.io/angular-material-8-data-table-pagination-sorting-tutorial/